# Requiring pandas dataframe input has either two column pairs or error thrown

Tags: python, pandas, csv, conditional-statements

I am writing a short program which takes a user-input *csv file and manipulates this as a pandas DataFrame.

Users must input the *csv with required columns `A1` and `B2` (including/without optional columns) or required columns `C3` and `D4` (including/without optional columns). If `A1` exists as a column, then `B2` must exist as a column, or there is an error thrown (and vice versa). Same with `C3` and `D4`. Uses are allowed to choose either pair, but they must chose.

Given an example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame("example1.csv")
```

I can individual check that the columns pairs must both exist as follows, either with pandas:

```
if df.columns.isin(['A1', 'B2']).any():
    raise ValueError("Both A1 and B2 must be included")
```

or with `.issubset()` as:

```
if not {'A1', 'B2'}.issubset(df.columns):
    raise ValueError("Both A1 and B2 must be included")
```

My problem is how to combine all of these conditionals together and not create spaghetti code.

If neither A nor B nor C nor D is found, throw an error. If one is found, check for the partner; if the required partner is not found, throw an error...(but this will fail if A, B, C exist and D doesn't and I chose C to find the pair...)

Comment: Your first method doesn't work as you'd expect. The second, however, does.

Comment: How about using `try..except` blocks to check for the second column once `if df.columns.isin(['A1', 'B2']).any():` statement is satisfied..

Comment: Also, what does the user choose? The CSV or the column pairs? Do they get to choose either D or C or only C?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I was unclear above: The user inputs a *csv. They have created the *csv. If they have created it incorrectly (by not including the mandatory column pairs), there must be an error

Comment: Okay. So you don't know what pairs the CSV contains, so you want to check for every column pair. Correct? What if the CSV has A and B, and C but not D? Should it succeed or fail?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ "What if the CSV has A and B, and C but not D?" In this case, it works. Now, for the downstream code, if the csv has A, B, C and D, then I will prioritize A B and use these columns

Comment: I think I understood. Please take a look at my answer and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of pairs -

```
pairs = {('A1', 'B2'), ('C3', 'D4')}
```

From your post, it seems it is sufficient for any one pair to exist. In which case, you can use a combination of `any` and `all` to do this -

```
if not any(any(x in df for x in p) and all(x in df for x in p) for p in pairs):
    raise ValueError("No valid pairs contained in `df`")
```

This roughly translates to:

```
for p in pairs:
    if any(x in df for x in p) and all(x in df for x in p):
        break
else:
    raise ValueError("No valid pairs contained in `df`")
```

Comment: `x` here is a column?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create list of lists with column pairs, loop through it and check your conditions:

```
col_pairs = [['A1', 'B2'], ['C3', 'D4']]
for pair in col_pairs:
    if set(pair).intersection(df.colums) and not set(pair).issubset(df.columns): 
        raise ValueError("Both {col1} and {col2} must be included".format(col1=pair[0], col2=pair[1]))
```

Comment: Sorry for mistake, `any(pair) in df` must be `set(pair).intersection(df.colums)`

Comment: Will `format(col1=pair[0], col2=pair[1]))` actually give users the correct pair needed? It may be either `A1` and `B2` or `C3` and `D4`, correct?

Comment: It'll give a user the first problem pair encountered.